# Stacked collapsable menu's in Bootsrap causing conflicts

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the following piece of code.

```
<header style="position: fixed; z-index: 999999; width: 100%;">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style=" position: relative; margin-bottom:0;">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <a class="navbar-company" href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk">&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 nav-small">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-product" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-product" class="navbar-collapse collapse mainlist">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/salonlite/">Salonlite</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/premiersalon/">Premier Salon</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/premierspa/">Premier Spa</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Core by Premier Software</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/collegebypremier/">College by Premier Software</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li>
                            <a href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>-->
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/vacancies/">Careers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/gappt/">Partners</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/support/">Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">News<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/news/">Premier News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/blog/">Premier Blog</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle grey" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <h4 class="logintxt">Client Login</h4>
                                <p class="logintxt">Premier Softwares client login area allows you to manage your online premier web booking.</p>
                                <form class="form" id="dologin" action="../Web-Portal/doLogin.php" method="post"> 
                                    <input name="txtSerial" id="txtSerial" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Serial number"> 
                                    <input name="txtPostCode" id="txtPostCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Postcode">
                                                                            <button type="submit" id="login-submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default product-nav-bar">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-push-3 col-sm-push-3 col-lg-push-2 remove-padding-and-center col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
                <a class="call" href="tel:01543466580">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div>01543 4666580</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-pull-3 col-lg-pull-3">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-push-2 nav-small">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="book-consultation-nav">
                            <a href="#contact-us" class="scroll-to" >Book a FREE Consultation</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-small-contact-us">
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#contact-details">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#marketing">Overview</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#features">Key Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#additional-reasons">In-Depth</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-small-brochure">
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#brochure">View Core Brochure</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#casestudies">Testimonials</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll-to" href="#contact-details">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs col-lg-pull-5 col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
                <a class="btn btn-primary book-consultation scroll-to" href="#contact-us" role="button">Book a FREE Consultation</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
<script>    
$(".scroll-to").on('click', function(event) 
    {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -153
                }, 800, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } 
    });
</script>
```

I'm using bootstrap and have two collapsible navigation on top of each other. When I select on of the options in the lower navigation in smaller screens (ie mobile screens), the top navigation opens.

To see this in action please visit:

http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/corebypremier/index9.php

Really I would just like the lower navigation animate the page without the top one opening.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Linking to commercial web sites is discouraged.  It is preferable to create a page as small as possible that illustrates the problem.